# React hover/active/focus style css selector not working for enclosed element

Tags: css, reactjs

i want to make a dropdown menu on butto hover, but when hovered, the effect
are not applying to any other element like `div` or `body`.
this is the code

here is a link to my code if you really like to dive in [search for dropbtn:hover](https://codepen.io/eladonline/pen/provJO?editors=0110)

```
.dropbtn:hover .dropdown-content {
  background: green ; //tried !important also not working
  display:block;
 }
```

Comment: To apply style to `.dropbtn:hover` **AND** to `.dropdown-content` you should separate them with comma: `.dropbtn:hover, .dropdown-content {...}`

Comment: i want to change .dropdown-content ,background and display. when hovering .dropbtn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `dropdown-content` is not a child of your `.dropbtn`, so `.dropbtn:hover .dropdown-content` won't work.
You could use `+` selector:

```
&:hover {
  & + .dropdown-content{
     background: green;
     display:block;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector is no good, `.dropbtn:hover .dropdown-content`, means that your `.dropdown-content` should be contained by  `.dropbtn`, in the HTML they are next to each other. You should change the HTML to make `.dropdown-content` child of `.dropbtn`, or you could change the selector into `.dropbtn:hover + .dropdown-content`